# How to read a specific data from a yaml file inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, yaml

I have a yaml file say "test.yaml". The below is the content of yaml file.

```
...
test:
  config:
    abc: name1
    xyz: name2
...
```

Now I want to read the value of abc and xyz alone from the yaml inside a shell script and store it in two variables inside shell script. test.yaml file contains additional data apart from the above one which I don't need to bother about that inside this shell script.

Eg: test.sh

```
var1=name1 //test[config[abc]]
var2=name2 //test[config[xyz]]
```

How do I read specific data (as key-value) from yaml inside a shell script. It would be really helpful if someone helps me out on this. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Use a proper YAML parser like `yq` - See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info

Comment: @Inian Thanks will check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example with [yq](/questions/tagged/yq). All of the following assumes that the values do not contain newlines.

Given

```sh
$ cat test.yaml
---
test:
  config:
    abc: name1
    xyz: name2
```

then

```sh
yq e '.test.config | to_entries | map(.value) | .[]' test.yaml
```

outputs

```
name1
name2
```

---

You can read them into variables like

```sh
{ read -r var1; read -r var2; } < <(yq e '.test.config | to_entries | map(.value) | .[]' test.yaml)
declare -p var1 var2
```

```
declare -- var1="name1"
declare -- var2="name2"
```

---

I would read them into an associative array with the yaml key though:

```sh
declare -A conf
while IFS="=" read -r key value; do conf["$key"]=$value; done < <(
    yq e '.test.config | to_entries | map([.key, .value] | join("=")) | .[]' test.yaml
)
declare -p conf
```

```
declare -A conf=([abc]="name1" [xyz]="name2" )
```

Then you can write

```sh
echo "test config for abc is ${conf[abc]}"
# or
for var in "${!conf[@]}"; do printf "key %s, value %s\n" "$var" "${conf[$var]}"; done
```

---

I'm using "the Go implementation"

```sh
$ yq --version
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.16.1
```

Comment: I might get some downvotes for providing a specific answer to a "low quality" question, but I find jq and yq sufficiently difficult that more examples online is helpful.

Comment: if you are suggesting answers with yq, please tag the appropriate version along with it. There are two implementations of it, the Python (wrapper over jq) and a Go version. Their DSLs are not quite the same. See the tag info comment I posted in the question